# How can I have a shell script point to a .dll? (Docker ENTRYPOINT)

Tags: .net, bash, shell, docker

I am using Docker to deploy a .NET Core application. By default, the `ENTRYPOINT` in the DockerFile for an application is something like:

`ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "applicationStartingPoint.dll"]`

However, I need to have a shell script execute in the container before the application begins. The `CMD` designation is not working for me for this purpose, so I need to have a shell script as my `ENTRYPOINT` and then have that start the application by the DLL.

Any insight you could provide would be greatly beneficial.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simply create a script called `entrypoint.sh`. Inside of this script you can do whatever you want, then call the command to start the application. So:

**entrypoint.sh**:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

... my crazy pre-script

dotnet applicationStartingPoint.dll
```

**Dockerfile**:

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

**UPDATE:** I've added to the Dockerfile how you can copy the file to the container while building it and also give the necessary permissions.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I tried this, but my containers keep exiting after the script executes, indicating to me that the "dotnet appstartpoint.dll" line in the script didn't work. This is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish though, if I could get that command to work, I would be so happy. Hmm.

Comment: does it gives a better clue on why the command doesn't work? You can debug it by getting inside by running the container with: docker run -it --entrypoint="/bin/sh" my_image. Then from there, debug your commands and see what's missing from you to have it work. Check the specially the permissions and if all the files were correctly copied inside the container.

Comment: Sorry I've fixed the command to get inside: docker run -it --entrypoint="/bin/sh" my_image

Comment: Another interesting thing to make it clear for you is that: CMD commands are run AFTER the container is up. You can also run commands WHILE the container is being build by using the RUN command on the Dockerfile.

Comment: I did it! I really can't thank you enough. Your assistance really helped me to solve the problem. Learned a lot. Thank you!!

Comment: My pleasure :-]

Comment: RUN echo "#!/bin/bash \n dotnet ${CSPROJ_FILENAME}.dll --urls=http://0.0.0.0:80" > ./entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x ./entrypoint.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]